# www prefix not showing site

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm trying to make my site work with the www prefix. I can only reach the site without the prefix. I am using Nginx+Django in digitalocean. Here is my site config file:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server{

listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

server_name .example.com;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

index index.html index.htm;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 5;

# Your Django project's media files - amend as required
location /media  {
    alias /home/django/proyect/media;
}

# your Django project's static files - amend as required
location /static {
    alias /home/django/proyect/static;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

}

I have tried without success these:

```
#    rewrite ^ http://example.com$uri permanent;
#    rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
#    server_name example.com www.example.com;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have DNS record for www?

Answer (score 1):

For my site I set it up so all www traffic was sent to the non-www address of my site by having two server blocks, one to redirect www traffic to the non-www address and one the handle the non-www traffic. I think the opposite should work for your situation.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it as I'm still pretty new to Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

The $host variable can be used to check for the occurrence of a "www" prefix. You could add this to the server section of the config to remove it:

```
 server {
    if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
       set $host_without_www $1;
       rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
    }
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

goto : DNS -> SELECT DOMAIN -> ADD RECORD -> Select record type "A"

hostname : www
IP Adress : your droplets IP